# How update and unlink image from image folder using livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm use this controller for trying to unlink my images from folder and database. It is successfully being deleted from database. But I can't unlink images from my folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User as TableUser;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class User extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $ids;
    public $user;
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $photo;
    public $photoOld;


    public function detail($id)
    {
        $user = TableUser::where('id', $id)->first();
        $this->ids = $user->id;
        $this->name = $user->name;
        $this->email = $user->email;
        $this->password = $user->password;
        $this->photoOld = $user->photo;
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'photo' => 'required|image|max:1024',
        ]);

        if ($this->ids) {
            $photo = $this->photo->store('photos', 'public');
            if (preg_match('/photos/', $this->photo)) {
                unlink(public_path('photos/' . $this->photo));
            }
        } else {
            $photo = $this->photoOld;
        }

        $data = TableUser::find($this->ids);
        $data->update([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($this->password),
            'photo' => $photo,
        ]);

        $this->resetform();

        $this->emit('closemodaledit');
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The requested resource /storage was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50', 'min:5'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:60', 'unique:users,email,' . $this->modelId,],
        'password' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'], // if you not have password confirmed remove (confirmed)
        'photo' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:650',
    ];
}

public function updatedPhoto()
{
    $this->validate([
        'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1024',
    ]);
}

public function update()
{

    if ($this->validate()) {
        $data = [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'username' => $this->username,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ];

        if (!empty($this->password)) {
            $validatedData = $this->validate([
                'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
            ]);
            $data['password'] = Hash::make($validatedData['password']);
        }

        if (!empty($this->photo)) {
            $namePhoto = $this->avatar->store('photos', 'public');
            $data['photo'] = $namePhoto;
        } else {
            $data['photo'] = $this->photoOld;
        }

        $user = TableUser::where('id', $this->ids)->update($data);

    }
    $this->resetform();

    $this->emit('closemodaledit');

}
```